# JSON parsing in React Native to get Array of String

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

In react native in the following `JSON` I need to get an `array` of `string` ["abc description", "def description", "ghi description" and so on] for value of `DataHolder`. There could be n number of `dictionary` in `DataHolder`

```
{
  "StatusCode": 200,
  "Description": "Description",
  "Message": "Success",
  "Response": {
    "Data": {
      "DataHolder": [
        {
          "abc": "abc description"
        },
        {
          "def": "def description"
        },
        {
          "ghi": "ghi description"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I am new in react-native any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you would just like to restructure the data from an API response. Here is one solution:

```
const data = {
    ...
    "Response": {
        "Data": {
            "DataHolder": [
                {
                    "abc": "abc description"
                },
                {
                    "def": "def description"
                },
                {
                    "ghi": "ghi description"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
};
const descriptions = data.Response.Data.DataHolder.map(item => Object.values(item)[0]);

// ["abc description", "def description", "ghi description"]
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be using JSON library

```
 const tempJSON = {
      "StatusCode": 200,
      "Description": "Description",
      "Message": "Success",
      "Response": {
        "Data": {
          "DataHolder": [
            {
              "abc": "abc description"
            },
            {
              "def": "def description"
            },
            {
              "ghi": "ghi description"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }

    let resultJSON = JSON.stringify(tempJSON)
    resultJSON = JSON.parse(resultJSON)

    console.log(resultJSON.Response.Data.DataHolder)
```

log result

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {abc: "abc description"}
1: {def: "def description"}
2: {ghi: "ghi description"}
```